Solving $c_{n} - 4c_{n-1} + 4c_{n-2} = 3$, where $c_{0} = c_{1} = 11$

Consider the following non-homogeneous recurrence relation \begin{equation} c_{n} - 4c_{n-1} + 4c_{n-2} = 3 \end{equation} where $c_{0} = c_{1} = 11$.

I am trying to derive the generating function $C_{1}(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_{n}x^{n}$ and separately solve the recurrence relation by homogenizing it first.

To find the generating function I multiply both sides by $x^{n}$ and sum over $n\geq 2$. Simplifying leads to the following expression \begin{equation} C(x) - a_{0} - a_{1}x -4x(C(x) - a_{0}) + 4x^{2}(x) = \frac{3x^{2}}{(1-x)}.\end{equation} By factorizing and inserting the known values for $a_{0}$ and $a_{1}$, I arrived at $$C(x) = \frac{11 - 33x}{(1-4x+4x^{2})} + \frac{3x^{2}}{(1-x)(1-4x+4x^{2})} \tag{1}$$

To homogenize the recurrence relation, note that $c_{n-1} = 4c_{n-2}-4c_{n-3} + 3$. If we subtract this relation from $c_{n} = 4c_{n-1} - 4c_{n-2} + 3$ we get: \begin{equation} c_{n} - c_{n-1} = 4c_{n-1} - 8c_{n-2} + 4c_{n-3} \Rightarrow c_{n} = 5c_{n-1} - 8c_{n-2} + 4c_{n-3},\end{equation} where $c_{0} = c_{1} = 11$ and $c_{2} = 3$. This recurrence relation has characteristic polynomial $x^{3} - 5x^{2} + 8x - 4 = (x-1)(x-2)^{2}$. Thus
\begin{equation} c_{n} = (A + Bn)2^{n} + C. \end{equation} With the initial conditions we get a system of equations, which can be solved after which we get $A = 8$, $B = -4$ and $C = 3$.


My first question is whether these solutions are correct, but one thing is troubling me in particular. Note that using our values for $A$, $B$ and $C$ we can also write:
\begin{equation}
C(x) = \frac{8}{(1-2x)} - \frac{4}{(1-2x)^{2}} + \frac{3}{(1-x)} \tag{2}.
\end{equation}
But after checking, the partial fraction expansion of (1) is not equal to (2)? Should they not be equal? The last two terms are the same, perhaps I made a computational mistake that I am unable to see.
Any help is appreciated!
Edit The expression in (2) is obtained by substituting the suitable values in the following general formula for $C(x)$
\begin{equation}
C(x) = \frac{A_{1, 1}}{1- \alpha_{1}x} + \dots + \frac{A_{1,m_{1}}}{(1-\alpha_{1}x)^{m_{1}}} + \dots + \frac{A_{j,1}}{1-\alpha_{j}x} + \dots + \frac{A_{j,m_{j}}}{(1-\alpha_{j}x)^{m_{j}}}
\end{equation}
where $\alpha_{j}$ are roots of the characteristic polynomial with respective multiplicity $m_{j}$ and $A_{j, m_{j}}$ are constants (in place for $A$, $B$, $C$ etc.) Hopefully this clarifies where I got (2) from.

(1) and $c_{n} = (A + Bn)2^{n} + C$ are both correct, but (2) is incorrect.
After your edit, you used constants from $c_n$ as constants to get partial fraction decomposition of its generating function - these are not the same constants! That explains why is your (2) wrong.
The below is the old answer, where I assumed you got (2) in a different way. However, you can still use it to see how to get from your $c_n$ to the generating function $C(x)$, and then find its partial fraction decomposition. I don't know why you would want it, but you can compare it with partial fractions decomposition of (1) to see you got the same result. (More typical scenario would be to use (1) and its partial fractions decomposition to get to $c_n$, and then compare that with $c_n$ you got by the second approach).

(before edit)
You did not specify how you got to (2), but I suspect you just evaluated infinite series $\sum c_n x^n$ by evaluating as three separate sums. In that case you made a mistake in evaluation of one of the infinite series, we have
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} Bn2^nx^n=Bx\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{d}{dx}(2x)^n=Bx\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (2x)^n=Bx\frac{d}{dx} \frac{1}{1-2x}=\frac{2Bx}{(1-2x)^2}.
$$
So with $B=-4$ the corrected (2) should be
\begin{equation}
C(x) = \frac{8}{(1-2x)} - \frac{\color{blue}{8x}}{(1-2x)^{2}} + \frac{3}{(1-x)} \tag{2}.
\end{equation}
However this expression is not in a form of partial fractions decomposition, we have merely summed infinite series. Of course, you can find its decomposition and verify it is the same as for $(1)$. You will find that
$$
C(x)=\frac{12}{1-2x}-\frac{4}{(1-2x)^2}+\frac{3}{1-x}.
$$
This actually agrees with corrected $(2)$, it's just written in a different way (in particular notice that $\frac{8x}{(1-2x)^2}=\frac{4}{(1-2x)^2}-\frac{4}{1-2x}$). It is the same you get by partial fractions decomposition of $(1)$.

Thank you for your response. I have one question, using a program I know (1) has a partial fraction expression of $\frac{12}{1-2x} - \frac{4}{(1-2x)^{2}} + \frac{3}{1-x}$ which equals my expression (2) except for the first term. What would my mistake have been? And what would be a general solution for $c_{n}$ not in terms of $x$?

One is partial fraction decomposition, and the other is evaluating infinite series $\sum c_n x^n$, by splitting to three sums $\sum A2^nx^n$, $\sum Bn2^nx^n$ and $\sum Cx^n$, the result is the generating function in form of (2), but this is not necessarily in a form of partial fractions. You can convert (2) to partial fractions and you will see it will be the same you get from (1).

I've updated my answer to clarify this, they are simply different ways to write the same function - after correcting your expression (2). The real mistake lies somewhere in your derivation of (2), which you have not shown.

Use Z transform to find $c(n) = 3 + 2^{n+3} - 2^{n+2} n$.

@Sil Thank you for your thorough response. I have one remaining question, I have made an edit to clarify where I got (2) from. Using this expression, we would arrive at $c_{n} = [x^{n}]C(x) = (A + Bn)2^{n} + C$ if I'm not mistaken. Perhaps the formula I used is incorrect, but are my values for $A$, $B$ and $C$ correct? Once again, thank you for your help.

Your constants $A,B,C$ in $c_n$ are correct, but those are in general different than those used in partial fractions decomposition $\frac{a}{1-2x}+\frac{b}{(1-2x)^2}+\frac{c}{1-x}$, there is your problem. I have, again, updated the answer, I guess my hope is we converge to some understanding. Also I would be careful with using the same variable $C$ for constant and for generating function $C(x)$...

Thank you @Sil, it is clear to me now!

Use the Z transform:
Apply to the defining equation and solve to find the Z transform of c(n) is:
$$Z[c(n)] = \frac{11 z^3-44 z^2+36 z}{(z-2)^2 (z-1)}$$
Perform the inverse Z transform with the initial conditions to find:
$$c(n) = -2^{n+2} n+2^{n+3}+3$$
